# log4j XML config file and Spring messageSource

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, log4j

I've got a few Spring XML config files (core, security, database), and pair of properties files (dev and prod).

It's very easy to use properties in XML; `${jdbc.password}`, for example.

But now I have to include those `.properties` in my Log4j XML configuration file, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
                     xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

<appender name="smtp" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
        <param name="BufferSize" value="1"/>
        <param name="SMTPProtocol" value="${mail.protocol}"/>
        <param name="SMTPHost" value="${mail.host}"/>
        <param name="SMTPPort" value="${mail.port}"/>
        <param name="SMTPUsername" value="${mail.address}"/>
        <param name="SMTPPassword" value="${mail.password}"/>
        <param name="To" value="${mail.to}"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} [%-5p][%-16.16t][%32.32c] - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

...

</log4j:configuration>
```

Is there any way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no relation between Spring and how log4j loads its configuration files.

Comment: Ok. But is there another way to use properties in non-Spring configuration XML?

Comment: Depends on the library. Look into log4j placeholders.